# Html/Java/Flash: Read clipboard content

Tags: java, html, flash, clipboard

I searched and searched over then internet and also on StackOverflow.

It is becoming a white beard.

I needed to process the contents of the clipboard copied from Excel and paste it into several text input by clicking a button on the webpage.

I do not need to do a CTRL-V in a hidden input and then every few seconds to look at the content, etc. etc.

Peremptory question:

There is no way to read the clipboard using "something"?
Tell me "NO" and I go to sleep

Carlo

Comment: In Java, access to the local clipboard was seen as a security threat, so that's out. In Flash (and I think things like Silverlight) I believe clipboard access is off by default, but the user can alter the settings to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class file with this text

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.*;

public final class clipboardData implements ClipboardOwner {

  public static void main(String...  aArguments ){
    clipboardData Clipboard = new clipboardData();
  }

   /**
   * Empty implementation of the ClipboardOwner interface.
     * @param aClipboard
     * @param aContents
   */
   @Override
   public void lostOwnership(Clipboard aClipboard, Transferable aContents){
     //do nothing
   }

  /**
  * Place a String on the clipboard, and make this class the
  * owner of the Clipboard's contents.
     * @param aString
  */
  public void setData(String aString){
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(aString);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, this);
  }

  /**
  * Get the String residing on the clipboard.
  *
  * @return any text found on the Clipboard; if none found, return an
  * empty String.
  */
  public String getData() {
    String result = "";
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    //odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    boolean hasTransferableText =
  (contents != null) &&
  contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    if (hasTransferableText) {
      try {
        result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
      }
      catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

The code above is accessible with this functions:

Create a new clipboard editor:

```
clipboardData clipboardData = new clipboardData()
```

setData function:

```
clipboardData.setData(Data)
```

getData function:

```
clipboardData.getData();
```